# Is it possible to create log based metrics in Google Cloud for missing data?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I'm trying to create a log based metric in Google Cloud that alerts when a certain log entry is no longer written to the logs.
Write now my application writes "Im alive" to the log every 30mins.
I'd like to create an alert that will alert if there is no "Im alive" written to the log after 45mins.

The idea is to be able to alert if an application which reads off a queue stops reading.

I am able to easily create an alert that alerts every time a log entry appear, but I would like to alert on the absence of a log entry.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your logs metrics and alert when the count of entries is below 1 over 30 minutes.

Cloud Monitoring can do that

Comment: Thanks I found if you create an alert from a custom log metric then there is an option to use "Metric Absence" is a condition for an alert to trigger.
Thanks for your help!